# Как найти ошибку в коде?

Tags: pascal

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49WuH.png)

с шестой строки выдает ошибку, хотя пишу с учебника, в чем проблема? 
Паскаль абсNET. Использование вещественных числе с целыми.

```
b:=n; writeln ('b=',b);
n:=trunk(a);writeln ('trunk'(3.6)=',n);
```

Comment: Строка указана с ошибой

Comment: А где же `begin`?

Comment: проверьте еще раз синтаксис по учебнику. У вас как минимум не хватает `begin`, и в строке 7 точно ошибка, из за кавычек. В 8й строке лишний знак равенства

Comment: да я увидела уже)) Жесть,опозорилась ))

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы)

Comment: еще в седьмой строке ошибся с кавычками

Comment: да,и в слове ошибка) не trunk,a trunc)

Comment: буду внимательнее)

Comment: На будущее: код лучше вставлять текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: @http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k Thanks.

Comment: @ElenaTeresa, чтобы написать в комментарии конкретному участнику, введите @ и первые буквы имени участника, после чего в подсказке выберите получателя. [Пример](http://image.prntscr.com/image/0e62f078f1e241f78c0c129eb30bf181.png).

Answer (score 1):

После третьей строки должен быть begin, на 7 строке второй апостроф - лишний.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы. Хотя плюс, у вас ответ правильный.

Comment: @AK, да ладно? о_О

Comment: Хм.. А почему компилятор на 4ю строку не ругается? Неужели так можно делать?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечая на вопрос, Как найти ошибку в коде?, могу сказать только одно.

1. Создайте пустую программу
2. Запустите - запустилось - хорошо, не запустилось ищите ошибку.
3. Добавляйте по одной строчке из вашего примера и запускайте - таким образом вы увидите какую строку перепечатали неверно!

Comment: Если добавить строку с Begin -- можно доооолго искать ошибку )